# Integrating with scipy quad using LowLevelCallable: How to pass user_data?

Tags: python, c, scipy

So I followed the [reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html#scipy.integrate.quad) how to use LowLevelCallable. The problem is, that I am apparently not able to pass arguments to the dblquad function as before (which would spoil up all my code which I wanted to speed up). My c-code looks as following:

```
#include <math.h>
// This function is f = ax + by
double f (int n, double *x) {
    return 2*(x[2]*x[0]+x[3]*x[1]);
}
```

And the python code then

```
import os, ctypes
from scipy import LowLevelCallable
from scipy.integrate import dblquad

lib = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.abspath('./testlib.so'))
lib.f.restype = ctypes.c_double

lib.f.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))

func = LowLevelCallable(lib.f)

for a in [1,2,3]:
    for b in [1,2,3]:
        print(dblquad(func, 0,1, lambda x: 0, lambda y: 1, args = [a,b])[0], a+b)
```

// Edit: There was a typo. Now it works. Nevermind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html), the tricky thing is to include your parameters in the array x, i.e. x = (x0, x1, ..., xn, t0, t1, ..., tm) where the x0,...xn are the coordinates.

Comment: Is there a difference between passing the arguments as args or as user_data like c_types? If so, do you know how can you pass more than one argument?